# Can security modules completely override Linux Kernel's access model?

Tags: linux, security, kernel-modules

I am aware of [Apparmor](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-apparmor) and specifically how it can be used to *limit* a program's access rights where of the file-system permissions otherwise allow.  What I'm less clear on is whether it's possible for Apparmor or any similar security module to completely override a program's access rights.  Can they *grant* a program access to read/write/execute files that the user otherwise has no access to.

I'm asking for what the Linux Kernel will allow such a security module to do, not what existing security modules can be configured to do.

Can security modules completely override Linux Kernel's access model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn’t seem to be mentioned in [the kernel’s LSM documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/security/lsm.html), but no, security modules can’t completely override the kernel’s access model, they supplement it.

For example, checks before execution include those in [`do_open_execat`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/fs/exec.c#L868), which checks the permissions; the LSM hooks are called later (look for `security_`). Other examples include all the functions in [`fs/namei.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/fs/namei.c) which call functions like [`may_delete`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/fs/namei.c#L2683) before the relevant LSM hooks.

Comment: That's a pity.  Thanks for the definitive answer!